# How to change background-color of Bootstrap column on hover?

Tags: html, css

I have a grid simulating a fake table made from divs using Bootstrap. I know how to change the background color of the `row` on `hover`. What I don't know is how to change the background of the div column on hover. I tried something but it's not working. Any ideas appreciated.

I've also made a **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0x18L3mr/)**.

My code so far:

```css
.fake_table{
    background: #fdf6e3;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.istoric_row:hover{
 background: #FEFAEE;
}
.td, .th {
  position: relative;
}
.td:hover::after,
.th:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffa;
  left: 0;
  top: -5000px;
  height: 10000px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="fake_table istoric_calendar">
  <div class="ft_header">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="col-md-4 th">Client</div>
      <div class="col-md-2 th">Added</div>
      <div class="col-md-6 th">
        <div class="clearfix">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="clearfix">
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                L
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                M
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                Mi
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                J
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="clearfix">
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                V
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                S
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                D
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                8
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ft_content mCustomScrollbar _mCS_1 mCS_no_scrollbar">
    <div id="mCSB_1" class="mCustomScrollBox mCS-dark mCSB_vertical mCSB_inside" style="max-height: none;" tabindex="0">
      <div id="mCSB_1_container" class="mCSB_container mCS_y_hidden mCS_no_scrollbar_y" style="position:relative; top:0; left:0;" dir="ltr">
        <div class="clearfix istoric_row">
          <div class="col-md-4 td">Lorem ipsum dolor / Lorem ipsum dolor / Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="col-md-2 td">6 months ago</div>
          <div class="col-md-6 td">
            <div class="clearfix">
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="clearfix">
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    1
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    2
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    3
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    4
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="clearfix">
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    5
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    6
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    7
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    8
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix istoric_row">
          <div class="col-md-4 td">Lorem ipsum dolor / Lorem ipsum dolor / Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="col-md-2 td">6 months ago</div>
          <div class="col-md-6 td">
            <div class="clearfix">
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="clearfix">
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    1
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    2
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    3
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    4
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="clearfix">
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    5
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    6
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    7
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    8
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix istoric_row">
          <div class="col-md-4 td">Lorem ipsum dolor / Lorem ipsum dolor / Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="col-md-2 td">6 months ago</div>
          <div class="col-md-6 td">
            <div class="clearfix">
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="clearfix">
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    1
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    2
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    3
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    4
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="clearfix">
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    5
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    6
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    7
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    8
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix istoric_row">
          <div class="col-md-4 td">Lorem ipsum dolor / Lorem ipsum dolor / Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="col-md-2 td">6 months ago</div>
          <div class="col-md-6 td">
            <div class="clearfix">
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="clearfix">
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    1
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    2
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    3
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    4
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="clearfix">
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    5
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    6
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    7
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    8
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix istoric_row">
          <div class="col-md-4 td">Lorem ipsum dolor / Lorem ipsum dolor / Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="col-md-2 td">6 months ago</div>
          <div class="col-md-6 td">
            <div class="clearfix">
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="clearfix">
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    1
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    2
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    3
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    4
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="clearfix">
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    5
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    6
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    7
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    8
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="mCSB_1_scrollbar_vertical" class="mCSB_scrollTools mCSB_1_scrollbar mCS-dark mCSB_scrollTools_vertical" style="display: none;">
        <div class="mCSB_draggerContainer">
          <div id="mCSB_1_dragger_vertical" class="mCSB_dragger" style="position: absolute; min-height: 30px; height: 0px; top: 0px;">
            <div class="mCSB_dragger_bar" style="line-height: 30px;"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="mCSB_draggerRail"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix total_saptamanal">
    <div class="col-md-4 th">Total 123</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 th">Total daily 22</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 th">
      <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              23
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              44
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              52
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              21
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              55
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              33
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              11
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              8
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you be more specific ? you want to change whose color when hovering on who ?

Comment: @MihaiT, Ok. When hovering a row and a column I need to change the background color of that row and column. I succeded with the row. But I have no idea how to do this for the column. I've seen this example but with tables here https://css-tricks.com/simple-css-row-column-highlighting/. But it's not working in my case.

Comment: it's not working because you have `.col-xs-3` as `td` . give the `after` to those, not to the `col-md-2`

Answer (score 0):

You can give it an extra class or even an ID, and just apply `background-color` on `.extraClass:hover` . You can add that class to multiple columns, too.

Comment: I already have multiple classes. I don't understand why I would need an extra one or how this helps me.

Comment: You will add that extra class to elements you want to change backgorund-color on hover. Or you want to do that to all columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
.td:hover{
    background: #ffa;
}
```

For tables (advanced or normal), I recommend using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/).